# php header location auto set http_response_code to 302 when it is 200 with php-fpm and nginx?

Tags: nginx, php

code like:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.google.com', TRUE, 200);
```

when run it in apache+php, the http_response_code is 200, but when run it in nginx + php-fpm, the http_response_code is 302.

what happens in nginx + php-fpm?

Comment: nginx+php-fpm is doing the 'correct' behaviour as documented in the manual. So the real question is what is happening in Apache + PHP.

Comment: yes, you are right. The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

Answer (score 2):

after read the source code of nginx, i found in /src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c, line 1564, there are some code about set status code to 302.

`header('Location: http://www.google.com', TRUE, 200);`

the response code 200 will not pass to nginx by fpm, so the response code will set to 302